# Ajax calls in Zend MVC

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, zend-framework

Im completely new to Zend Framework and the concept of MVC as well. What I want to do is make an Ajax request which returns exactly the data that I specified in my view (.phtml) file.

The problem I am having right now is that the contents of my .phtml file is being sandwiched between html footers and headers (an entire new HTML page is being returned). What is the best approach for getting just the raw data? Solutions or just a nudge in the right direction will be most appreciated!

EDIT: Upon further research it looks like I'm trying to do a RPC call, which according to this lecture [PDF](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.thinkfree.com%2Ftools%2Fdownload.php%3Fmode%3Ddown%26dsn%3D860056&rct=j&q=%22the%20individual%20resources%20and%20units%20of%20work%22&ei=O9cQTdmqDNjUnAeP1ajiDQ&usg=AFQjCNEnpUSZCU40ni3zESDnjPhbIIybqg) (slide 51), I should totally bypass MVC for this purpose. is this correct?

Comment: Now it's a dead link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heximal's answer is a good place to start.  A more bare-bones (and **not** a good way to do it, but simple) would be something like the following action:

```
function ajaxDataAction(){
    $data = getMyDataAsString(); //could be XML, JSON, etc.  
    die($data); //since we're dying, no view or layout rendering happens.
}
```

But don't do that.

Instead, have a look at the [ContextSwitch and AjaxContent view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) (section is about 25% of the way down the page)

Comment: My application will need to use a lot of Ajax and performance is required. I think that rendering a template only to return a json content would be much overhead, or not? Would not it be better to use something like this in the controller (In the preDispatch method for example): `$this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($this->data))->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')->sendResponse().exit`? I thought of the possibility of having only a single module to handle Ajax requests, it would be a good practice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

within your ActionController try this:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->renderScript('myview/myview.phtml');
```

where myview - is path to views ./application/views/scripts/myview

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I am curious if this is even the right approach, can you check my edited OP?